# git и Visual Studio. Как откатить состояние проекта к определенному коммиту?

Tags: visual-studio, git, visual-studio-2015

Конечно можно 2 раза нажать на коммит и в Team Explorer появятся файлы, которые были изменены, но это не очень удобно.
Можно ли состояние проекта "заменить" на состояние какого либо коммита, просто чтобы посмотреть что и как было на тот момент, без удаления других коммитов и создания новых?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я нашел пока один вариант: ПКМ по коммиту - View details(детали коммита), в окне, где появятся детали коммита открываем Actions(на русском скорее всего действия) -> Copy Commit ID, далее переходим в консоль GIT - и делаем git checkout <commit ID>

Comment: @A1essandro, если найдёте другой вариант (помимо `checkout`) — обязательно напишите торвальдсу, порадуйте старика новыми неизведанными возможностями. (это шутка. я конечно, знаю и про `show`, и про `cat-file`, и про ещё более изощрённые пути, но «каноническим» является, естественно, только `checkout`).

Comment: Я попробовал с помощью программы Git Extention откатить ветку к определенному более раннему коммиту. Откатил, открыл проект, состояние его никак не изменилось, только добавились красные галки у некоторых файлов.
https://s17.postimg.org/f7t9dfw0f/image.png

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, чет не понял шутку. Даже если гуглить (я с git-ом не очень часто работаю, в основном mercurial) "перейти на определенный коммит git" то выдает чекаут. Объясните, пожалуйста, если я не прав.

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади, скорее всего Вы именно откатили изменения (т.е. сделали revert https://githowto.com/ru/undoing_committed_changes)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если я правильно понял Вашу шутку, то мой ответ такой: автор спрашивал именно про Team Explorer в VS. Лично я не нашел вообще как это сделать в студии, максимум скопировать ID коммита.

Comment: @A1essandro, в данном случае «сделать в студии» полностью эквивалентно чему-нибудь вроде «сделать в компьютере». единственный канонический путь — использовать команду `checkout` программы *git*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы нашлось благодаря Павлу Горошкову тут: https://vk.com/wall-38655318_37990

В самой Visual Studio такого сделать не получится.
Я установил программу Git Extensions и в ней открыл репозиторий/папку с проектом Visual Studio. Там выбрал коммит, ПКМ по нему и выбрал "Откатить текущую ветку сюда" и в появившемся окне выбрать "Жёсткий:......"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Аналогично в студии "Сброс -> С удалением изменений (hard)".

Comment: Без потери коммитов, но с переключением рабочей директории -- на скриншоте кнопка "Переключиться на ревизию". Как раз что вам советовали в комментариях. В студии аналогичной кнопки не нашел.

Comment: а git checkout? Т.е перейти в нужный репозиторий и git checkout с идентификатором нужного коммита.

Answer (score 2):

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы только посмотреть коммит не создавая новых и не откатываясь по дереву коммитов, то самое простое - создать отдельную ветку.
Нажимаем ПКМ в Visual Studio на текущую ветку (справа внизу окна) и выбираем View History... Появится вкладка с деревом коммитов.

Нажимаем ПКМ на нужном коммите и выбираем New Branch... (при этом все изменения текущей ветки должны быть закоммичены, иначе после создания ветки нельзя будет на неё переключиться). После того, как поработали с новой веткой, её можно удалить в Team Explorer (предварительно переключившись на другую ветку).